# JasperReports: Items is pdf are printing on top of each other instead of beside each other

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I'm using *JasperReports* to generate pdf files for customers. For some reason some items are stacking on top of each other instead of printing beside like they are supposed to.

Here is a design of my report:
[image: The report's design]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a little info about the report layout? Is it possible that the wrapping happens because there is just barely enough space for 2 letters... but then the report uses a different font, so then there's only room for 1 letter per line?

Comment: The stacking only happens when there is two characters. When there is more than two it displays properly. What specifically would you like to know about the layout?

Comment: From the image it's not clear how wide the fields are. Is it possible that the wrapping happens because there is just barely enough space for 2 letters? Maybe the best would be to post the .jrxml somewhere with a query that returns some dummy data.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have the "Position Type" set to "Fix Relative to Top". Change it to "Float".

**EDIT**: I just received a sample report showing the same behavior. It looks like a bug to me. In that case I got the desired output by appending a space. "JG" would break into 2 lines. But "JG " would be rendered on a single line. I cannot explain this. It's clearly a bug. But if you are hitting the same behavior, then appending a space might solve it for you as well.

Comment: That didnt work out. I am going to post a picure of what it is doing